# flurry analytics dashboard download as pdf

Tags: pdf, dashboard, flurry

I have implemented Flurry analytics for my app. Flurry allows CSV downloads of the report. However it does not have features like PDF download or email for the graphs, reports and dashboards

Is there any alternative to get PDF downloads of Flurry graphs and charts?

Comment: Seriously why doesn't flurry have the ability for developers to download a PDF of a report? You have to link into the API to get an info, sorry I don't have a couple hours to share this stuff, only a couple mins!

Answer (score 1):

From what I could find, the only way to get flurry data is in CSV or JSON form.  There is flurry API that allows data export.  On flurry website go to help, flurry API.
http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=API